# Understanding arcpy log files in the scratchWorkspace

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, log

When I run a tool through arcpy, a file simply called 'log' with no extension is created in the scratchWorkspace. This is quite different to the history log files which are XML and I cannot find any documentation on it.

A line of this file typically looks something like:

```
201402261409   0     0     0Johnsmith C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\SnapPou_fA551 = SNAPPOUR(C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\t_t324, C:\Test Data\SampleFlowAcc\FlowAcc.tif,  10000.0)
```

So it seems the first column is a data/time stamp of the tool execution, then there are 2 numbers, followed by what must be the windows user who executed the tool and the tool command (with output & input locations)

I would like to know what the number columns mean? More often than not, these are both 0's, but sometimes the first column is a 1 and the second column is anything between 1 and 9...

Any ideas?

Here is a bigger example of the file contents:

```
201402261410   1     7     0Jhonsmith C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\Watersh_Flow1 = WATERSHED(C:\Test Data\SampleFlowDir\FlowDir_Fill11.tif, C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\SnapPou_fA641)
201402261410   0     0     0Johnsmith in_memory\f55D3000E_BE6E_4FF6_A15E_3B3ACA024F7E = GRIDSHAPE(C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\ws_6, WEED)
201402261410   0     0     0Johnsmith C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\SnapPou_f90E1 = SNAPPOUR(C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\t_t3211, C:\Test Data\SampleFlowAcc\FlowAcc.tif,  10000.0)
201402261410   0     9     0Johnsmith C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\Watersh_Flow1 = WATERSHED(C:\Test Data\SampleFlowDir\FlowDir_Fill11.tif, C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\SnapPou_f90E1)
201402261410   0     0     0Johnsmith in_memory\fAC52111C_9237_4398_897D_1E5D0A460157 = GRIDSHAPE(C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\ws_7, WEED)
201402261410   0     0     0Johnsmith C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\SnapPou_f8541 = SNAPPOUR(C:\temp\tmpeoqn0r\t_t3212, C:\Test Data\SampleFlowAcc\FlowAcc.tif,  10000.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, these files have been around for a long time but no obvious explanation of their structure. I've noticed that they often log raster processing operations as does your example show.  I came across these threads [[1]](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=125874&mc=2#msgid363016)[[2]](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_the_ESRI_grid_format)[[3]](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000281.shtml) but none of them explicitly describe the structure of the log file. I don't think its documented anywhere and probably a relic to ArcInfo 7 or earlier.

Comment: I would assume that the numeric columns relate to some kind of messages generated by the tool? It would be interesting to know as they could provide a much clearer 'quick reference' as to what has happened than the xml history log files and they exist in the workspace, which is a more sensible location...

Comment: Lets hope someone from ESRI sees this and can give an answer as I cannot find anything in their help files.